# GLKit does not display texture when using GL_MODULATE with alpha in vertex color

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glkit

I have a texture image that I am using with GLKit.  If I use GL_MODULATE on the texture and have vertex RGBA (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) then the texture shows up entirely as it would do in GL_REPLACE.  Fully opaque.
Then if I use Red (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) for vertex RGB the texture shows up again as Red modulating the texture.
So far so good.
But when I change the transparency in the vertex color and I use RGBA(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5), then only a light red color is seen and the texture is not visible, so the color is replacing the texture entirely. 
The texture itself has no alpha, it is RGB565 texture.
I am using GLKit with GLKTextureEnvModeModulate.

```
self.effect.texture2d0.envMode = GLKTextureEnvModeModulate;
```

Any help on why the texture would disappear, when I specify the alpha?

Adding snapshots:

[image: Original Texture]
This is the original texture

[image: RGBA (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)]
RGBA (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) - white color , no premultiplication, opaque, texture visible

[image: RGBA (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5)]
RGBA (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5) - white color, no premultiplication, alpha = 0.5, texture lost

[image: RGBA (1.0, 0, 0, 1.0)]
RGBA (1.0, 0, 0, 1.0) - red color , no premultiplication, opaque, texture visible

[image: RGBA (1.0, 0, 0, 0.5)]
RGBA (1.0, 0, 0, 0.5) - red color, no premultiplication, alpha = 0.5, texture lost

[image: RGBA (0.5, 0, 0, 0.5) - after premutiplying a = 0.5 per @andon]
RGBA (0.5, 0, 0, 0.5) - red color, premultiplication, alpha = 0.5 per @andon, texture visible, but you may need to magnify to see it

[image: RGBA (0.1, 0, 0, 0.1) - after premutiplying a = 0.5 per @andon]
RGBA (0.1, 0, 0, 0.1) - red color, premultiplication, alpha = 0.1 per @andon, texture lost, probably because not enough contrast is there

[image: RGBA (0.9, 0, 0, 0.9) - after premutiplying a = 0.5 per @andon]
RGBA (0.9, 0, 0, 0.9) - red color, premultiplication, alpha = 0.9 per @andon, texture visible, but you may need to magnify to see it

Comment: The texture itself has no alpha in it.  So while loading it generates a 565 RGB image.  So I guess it means that the alpha is 1 and premultiplied.  My blend function is for pre-multiplied - One, One - Src.  I am experimenting if 565 itself is a problem and somehow the GLKit shaders fail to work if texture alpha is missing.  So my next plan is to generate a texture that has alpha in it, even if it be 1, and see if GLKit works any differently.

Comment: Like I said, alpha is already a constant **1.0** when you use 565 (or any RGB format). It is just one of those things that GL does for you automatically, the 4th component of a vertex attribute or color is assigned **1.0** if not explicitly stored. Given your blend function, you should adjust the vertex color accordingly, that means multiplying its RGB by its A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The texture itself has no alpha, it is RGB565 texture

`RGB565` implicitly has constant alpha (opaque -> **1.0**). *That may not sound important, but modulating vertex color with texture color does a component-wise multiplication and that would not work at all if alpha were not **1.0**.*

> My blend function is for pre-multiplied - One, One - Src.

This necessitates pre-multiplying the RGB components of vertex color by the A component. ***All** colors must be pre-multiplied, this includes texels and vertex colors.*

#### You can see why below:

```
Vtx = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5)
Tex = (R,   G,   B,   1.0)

// Modulate Vertex and Tex
Src = Vtx * Tex = (R, 0, 0, 0.5)

// Pre-multiplied Alpha Blending (done incorrectly)
Blend_RGB = Src * 1    +  (1 - Src.a) * Dst
          = Src        +          Dst / 2.0
          = (R, 0, 0)  +          Dst / 2.0
```

The only thing this does is divide the destination color by 2 and add the unaltered source color to it. It is ***supposed*** to resemble linear interpolation *(`a * c  +  (1 - c) * b`)*.

#### Proper blending should look like this:

```
// Traditional Blending
Blend_RGB = Src * Src.a   +  (1 - Src.a) * Dst
          = (0.5R, 0, 0)  +          Dst / 2.0
```

This can be accomplished using the original blend function if you multiply the RGB part of the vertex color by A.

#### Correct pre-multiplied alpha blending <sub>(by pre-multiplying vertex color):</sub>

```
Vtx = (0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5) // Pre-multiply: RGB *= A
Tex = (R,   G,   B,   1.0)

// Modulate Vertex and Tex
Src = Vtx * Tex = (0.5R, 0, 0, 0.5)

// Pre-multiplied Alpha Blending (done correctly)
Blend_RGB = Src * 1       +  (1 - Src.a) * Dst
          = (0.5R, 0, 0)  +          Dst / 2.0
```

Comment: That was super helpful and very well explained.  Thanks.  I totally missed premultiplying the vertex color.   Yet, I still am not sure why the texture would vanish.   In my case I have the texture as darker grey hatched lines over a light gray background.  So with the explanation of how it works, should I not still see the Red component of the hatched lines?   So some kind of Red hatched lines on a red background?  I may not be thinking this through well, so I am going to try premultiply the vertex color too, and see if I get back the hatched lines.  I will report back.

Comment: ok, I think its as you said it.  I am trying to use a high transparency i.e. low alpha.  And when I do that and I premultiply it pulls down the red value too, so there is negligible difference between the hatched lines and the background.  So they disappear. I tried multiple values between R and A and there were some where the hatched lines showed up.  So maybe I need to start with darker hatched lines in the image for this to work.   But your explanation nailed it.  Thanks for the awesome clarity in your answer (and the math).

Comment: I think my texture was too subtle and in the modulation the vertex color is overwhelming the small differences so the vertex color was all that remains after the modulation.  I guess its a multiplication effect.

Comment: @nishant: If you can include a screenshot I can take a look at it in the morning. There may be some extra details I need to add. If this is for compositing multiple layers, then the alpha part of the blend equation (_you will notice the blend equation listed is for RGB only - I did this for simplicity_) will need to be discussed.

Comment: added in the snapshots. @andon  I also added those after premultiply.  The texture is there even if it seems barely visible.  You may need to magnify the browser to see it.

Comment: @nishant: I believe this is actually normal. You may want to try clearing the color buffer to `(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)` to see if that brings out hidden details in the second to last image. I think the clear color is overwhelming what little color exists in the modulated texture during blending.

Comment: ok, I will try that too!  Thanks for the help on this .  Greatly appreciated.  You taught me how to think about the tex env + blending mathematically, and that makes will make it easier to work things out.